# How to get configuration file from CI_PROJECT_DIR to use in service's command and get data from service as artifact

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

1.) I'd like  to get configuration file from repository files to start service according to configuration. However, as I see it doesn't see repository files when the services are started at first. Is there a way to do that? or Can I mount a folder or volume to service?

2.) After that, I just want to get service's data as artifact after scripts are completed. Is there a way to do that without redirecting data folder to $CI_PROJECT_DIR?

What are the best practices of these two issues?

Comment: Point 2. There's no way to create a GitLab-CI artifact outside the `CI_PROJECT_DIR`.